# I want to send and receive sms through serial comport using gsm modem in java

Tags: java, windows-xp, sms, gsm, at-command

I want to implement Java code to send and receive sms through serial comport using gsm modem. Before implementing this I need Java communication api for this. If so please let me know from where I have to download for Windows Xp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the download link for Java Communication API:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Comment: kamaci::Thanks alot !!!..but i need free download...please send me the free download link

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps but on one of my previous project we were using http://www.kannel.org/ to manage sms.

Don't remember exactly how it worked but i think we can set a kannel server that would receive REST requests to send sms for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Java communication api from http://smslib.org/download/. There are some other useful links on that page also like the RXTX library also.